# Discrete Mathematics - Logic gates so the lamp can glow

Tags: discrete-mathematics

In this chapter of the book I'm doing logic gates like these:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yuSP.png

But on the practice exam I'm given a completely different looking image compared to the logic gates in the book and I have no idea what to do to "make the lamp glow".

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZkw5.png

I'm not sure which is the OR gate, AND gate, and inverter gates. Could someone please explain to me what I'm supposed to do?

The correct answer is `P: True, and Q: False`.

Comment: There's no way we can answer this without understanding the notation. In order to solve this, you need to determine what the notation is that your class is using.

Comment: There was no notation? That was the full question on the exam https://i.imgur.com/J1CLsMX.png

Comment: The picture is obviously denoting something. You need to find the course materials where the professor explains the meaning of a diagram similar to this one so that you can explain enough to us about the meaning of the diagram that the problem becomes solvable.

Comment: Those are standard symbols for [logic gates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic_gate) and electrical components including [switches](https://electronicsclub.info/circuitsymbols.htm).

Comment: Basically, "$P$ is true" means that the $P$ gate will close, and the $\lnot P$ gate will stay open. "$Q$ is false" means that the $Q$ gate will stay open, while the $\lnot Q$ gate will close. This will create a closed circuit, which will make the lamp glow. None of the other options given will create a closed circuit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming the notation on the circuit diagram implies that $P$ leaves the switch labelled as P open while it closes the switch labelled as $\lnot P$.

Since there is no possible closed circuit that bypasses the lamp, any configuration of switches that creates a closed circuit works. In that case, the set of all solutions will be as written below:

$(\lnot R\land(P \lor Q))\lor(P\oplus Q)$

Note that if P is true and Q is false, then that satisfies the (P $\oplus$ Q) portion, and so the answer on the answer key describes one of the few ways to make the lamp glow. Other alternatives would be negating both of those, making R false and P true, or making R false and Q true.